# how to exclude a package from building in bazel?

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel, alpine-linux, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to build tensorflow-1.10.0 using bazel-0.16 in alpine 3.8. However it is giving me an error as mentioned below.

```
tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/internal/spectrogram.cc:46:22: error: 'tflite::internal::Log2Floor' declared as an 'inline' variable
inline int Log2Floor(uint n) {
                      ^~~~
tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/internal/spectrogram.cc:46:22: error: 'uint' was not declared in this scope
tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/internal/spectrogram.cc:244:1: error: expected '}' at end of input
 }  // namespace tflite
 ^
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
```

Commands I am using to build is:

```
bazel build --config=opt --cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

GCC and g++ version are 6.4 and 6.4 respectively. 
How can i avoid building of `tensorflow/contrib/lite` package, since I don't need to use it anyway.

Plus tensorflow-1.7.0 is getting build successfully, however tensorflow-1.10.0 is giving compilation issues as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type portability issue has been [fixed recently](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/20154feed54b667d5d9819aaa0d75626a6c02228), and should be in the upcoming 1.11 release. You can either:

- Try build from a checkout from master
- Wait for the 1.11 release
- Patch in [the fix](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/20154feed54b667d5d9819aaa0d75626a6c02228) to the 1.10 branch
- Manually edit the [build script](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/BUILD#L222) to remove the [`lite`-specific dependencies](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package.sh#L124).

Comment: Thanks jdduke... after applying the patch, was able to build successfully... however I bumped into this `tf.estimators package not installed` in build log. And tensorflow is giving segmentation fault if I try this code `hello = tf.constant('hello tensorflow')` . Any thoughts??